# Display user form in the top right corner of the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I need the userform I made to display in the top right corner of the worksheet. I think I can manually set the position but when the workbook is opened on a different computer with a different screen resolution the userform is almost completely off the screen. What is wrong with my VBA code below that is meant to make the userform position itself so that the whole thing is showing but in the top right of the screen? it's just not doing anything and I assume that's because the code is not right.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
     
    Me.StartUpPosition = 0
    Me.Top = Application.Top + 25
    Me.Left = Application.Left + Application.Width - Me.Width - 25
     
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not an expert here but [from the looks](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/671108-userform-startup-position.html) your code should work. Can you verify that this code is actually getting executed?

Comment: Well, you can set a breakpoint for the [debugger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1ARYg4ZJBA). Another way could be to write a message or open a message box.

Comment: You should learn what a debugger is. It is the most important tool for you as a programmer. Maybe watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1ARYg4ZJBA) or google "what is a debugger". Your code might be fine but you have to find out if it is being executed. If you're not interested in learning what a debugger is a lazy method would be to insert `MsgBox "Hello World!"` somewhere in your code and see if this message box appears or not.

Comment: I suggest that you google "vba how to show a message box" and grab [the first link](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/msgbox.html). Before or after that you should learn about a debugger. If you are not willing to do that I can promise you that you won't experience a lot of fun writing VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I'm confusing you more than helping.  You must understand that "Application.Width" is the whole width of the Excel window.  I think this code below will help you to understand the numbers.  Put it into a regular module, not the form module, not the sheet module.  When you run it it will debug.print out the numbers of your computer's resolution, total width of excel when maximize at your resolution, the total width of Excel when minimized at your resolution, and the total width of your userform. (Change it from Userform1 if you havde a different name for it.)

Every computer that runs your form might have different resolutions, and their screens might be maximized or minimized, we don't know these things.  But they are all variables that affect the total available width as to where to position the form. Think individual pixels.  If your form is 300 pixels wide and you position it on a screen that has 1000 pixels to work with, then the command to put the form on the very right edge of your screen would be me.left = 1000 - 300. (or application.width - me.width)  But if there is only 700 available pixels to work with then the command would be me.left = 700-300, or 400.

The command me.left is telling the computer to draw the leftmost pixel of the form at a certain spot.  So if yours is appearing on the left side (the same side of the screen as the "Start" or windows button), then you are telling it to draw the leftmost pixel at 0.  I don't know how better to explain it.

But put this in a module and run it.  It might help to see the actual numbers you have in your commands.

```
Public Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Const SM_CXSCREEN = 0
Const SM_CYSCREEN = 1
Sub VerifyScreenResolution2()

    Dim x  As Long
    Dim y  As Long

    x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
    y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)

    Debug.Print "This Computer Resolution Width:  " & x, "Resolution Height:  "; y
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
    Debug.Print "Application.Width Maximized:  " & Application.Width
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
    Debug.Print "Application.Width Minimized:  " & Application.Width
    Debug.Print "Userform1 Width:  " & UserForm1.Width

End Sub
```

Here are the printouts I get for my computer and form.

This Computer Resolution Width:  1366     
Resolution Height:   768 
Application.Width Maximized:  1036.5 
Application.Width Minimized:  120
Userform1 Width:  240

Comment: No, I don't know why it doesn't work. You need to right click anywhere in the editor's "Project" window (upper left) and click "insert" module. (Not class module)  Paste the above code into the new module. Click the "View" option up at the editor's top menu and click "Immediate Window" to make sure it is open.  The debug.print command will write to that window.  Place the cursor anywhere inside the subroutine and click PF5 to run it.  But honestly if you need this kind of instruction please get the book Excel VBA for Dummies.  It's excellent for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the userform module.  It works for me, but I'm running 1366 resolution.  Interestingly the applicaabovtion.width of Excel is showing 1033.5 for me.  I edited the subroutine in the other answer to debug.print what your values are.  Try replacing it in your userform module again.  Then  go back to the VBA editor and see what printed out  in the immediate window. That way you can test the different work stations with different resolutions and possibly find where it is going wrong. Just make sure you set View - Immediate Window in order to see what prints out.

If all else fails it might be that you will need to adjust for each users resolution.  Remember, 25 points in a 1600 resolution will be like 50 points in an 800 resolution.

```
Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Const SM_CXSCREEN = 0
Const SM_CYSCREEN = 1

Sub VerifyScreenResolution()

    Dim x  As Long
    Dim y  As Long

    x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
    y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)

    Debug.Print x, y

End Sub
```